# IIS application writing to a remote file share

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-server-2012

We have 2 servers in DMZ. First one is application server, let's call it APP machine. The other is a file server, let's call it FILE. Web site running on APP machine under IIS is trying to create a file in a shared directory located at FILE server.

When application pool is running with some user in IUSR_IUSRS or NETWORK SERVICE writing to remote location fails. I cant authorize this user in shared folder, because that FILE machine can only see local users.

I created a user X on APP machine (APP/X) and another one with the same username on FILE (FILE/X). Then I added FILE/X user to credential manager on APP machine. When APP/X and FILE/X users have different passwords writing fails again. But when passwords are the same then writing just works.

I cant understand why passwords matter. At the end of the day they are two different users APP/X and FILE/X. Could someone clarify this phenomenon?

Comment: Now, as to the credential manager item, when you added that, did you do so while logged in as the X user on APP?

Comment: @ChrisLively Yes. I know that each user have her own credential set in vault.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the local user account on APP attempts to connect to the FILE server it passes it's credentials (username and password).  If that combination isn't an exact match against a user on the FILE machine then it will fail.

There are multiple ways to do this "correctly".  The most common would be to have a domain setup in which the site on the APP server runs under.  That way you could just authorize the user to have rights on the FILE server.

If you can't have a domain controller, then the username and passwords must be kept in sync on the two machines.

Comment: So machine name is ignored? So its not APP/X indeed just X?

Comment: That's correct.  When the service attempts to connect to the remote machine it does not send it's own machine name in the user field.  It just sends the actual username.  The reason is to facilitate situations like this.  Otherwise it would be a bit harder to get things to work without a common authentication store like AD.